# Can urinating around camp attract wildlife?

Tags: safety, wild-camping, animals

As far as I know, it's generally a good idea to pee a fence around your camp. Don't know if it makes any major differences but ...

> It is true urinating around your tent will keep some critters away and
> a smoky fire helps also (...)
>
> *- From [Bear Crap](https://answers.yahoo.com/activity/questions?show=AIMXHPNE52YRQV77JLXIXTNZ6A&t=g) on [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100908152413AAm26vA)*

I wonder if there are any disadvantages doing so? For example, are any wildlife attracted to it?

Comment: Please don't do this if you are anywhere near my campsite!

Comment: Do you have a citation for this quote?

Comment: Hardly fits the LNT ethos. Would not take long to make camping 'unpleasant' in many places. I would rather put up with nature than a camp-site saturated in month old piss, mine or someone else's.

Comment: @ChrisMendez Not a good one though. I'll add it to my answer anyway :)

Comment: @OddDeer heh, better than nothing!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Backpacker](http://www.backpacker.com/gear/experts/ask-buck/pee-perimiter/), and the [National Park Service](http://www.nps.gov/noca/learn/nature/bear-safety.htm), peeing attracts some large predators because animals like the salty taste:

> ...urinate well away from camp on rock, sandy areas, or duff. Animals are attracted to salts in urine...

I would argue, therefore, that **urinating around your campsite is not a good idea when near large predatory animals.**

That said, I do it sometimes when car camping away from large predators.